# I press print screen and the screen resizes to full. How do I restore the screenshot functionality of print screen?

Tags: firefox, chromium, screenshot

What it says on the tin. I haven't made any changes that I'm aware of, but when I'm in a browser window (Firefox or Chromium), print screen switches it into full screen mode. Is there a way to revert to the original setting?

Comment: You can toggle full screen in Firefox or Chromium by pressing the F11 key.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. I want to take screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle full screen in Firefox or Chromium by pressing the <kbd>F11</kbd> key. Then you can show the screenshot options overlay interface by pressing the <kbd>PrtScn</kbd> key.

[image]
<sup>**screenshot options**</sup>